# Pull data from multiple Excel sheets, count how many of a certain lead within a month

Tags: vba, excel

A continuation of a previous question... where I have run into another formula issue.

We have an Excel spreadsheet where we track our leads. My boss wants to know, specifically "how many leads for each month and how many of each source and the result."

The users on this forum were incredibly helpful, and gtwebb gave me this formula (thank you!):

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A14:A21,12012)
```

Which worked beautifully for counting how many leads we had in each month.

Now I need to know how many leads came from the Web, SOI, VP/Sign, etc., WITHIN that month. So I'm hoping there is a formula where I can ask Excel to only look at a certain month, say 12012, and then how many leads we got from the Web or other places. I know I'll need to change our lead source for each formula, but I can't get the basic formula to work. I've tried: =countif(Sheet1!e2:e20,12012, if(Sheet1!m2:m20,Web)), and other variations on this, trying to elaborate on the original formula that worked correctly.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Pivot Table didn't really ring a bell with me, so I looked into a formula solution.

Pnuts posted a suggestion to try sumifs(). I could only get this to work if there was a column with "1" in it for every line.

A similar function, countifs(), seems to work. Here's a formula for counting the number of lines with a month of "12012" and a source of "Web":

```
    =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"=12012",Sheet1!B:B,"=Web")
```

It assumes that column A is month and column B is source. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am more comfortable using formulas, and don't understand how to use pivot tables. The countif() formula seems to work for what I need it to do. Since I keep encountering Excel problems, I am hoping to take an Excel class so I might understand all of this better. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Good luck~

Answer (score 0):

Your boss wants a Pivot Table made from the data. Unless you have other reasons for using formulas or VBA (not stated in the question), using the pivot table functionality instead will save you a lot of effort in this case.